# What is the difference between piecewise constant and piecewise smooth?

Tags: computer-vision, image-segmentation

In Image segmentation, these two terms, piecewise constant and piecewise smooth commonly appears. Can someone describe the differences?

Comment: Can you give some references to where you saw these terms for context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we talk about images, and image worth a thousands words...

Piecewise constant:
[image]

Piecewise smooth:
[image]

Comment: thanks for the nice image! Based on your image, the gradient on the piecewise constant is 0 on the left and right most values. But on the piecewise smooth, we have gradient <0 or >0 on the left and right most values.

Comment: that is correct, in piecewise smooth the gradient may actually change, but smoothly in each piece

Comment: You might also want to look at piecewise-continuous.

Comment: Amazing! Learned something new